# LyX Layout for TrueType Fonts

Tags: fonts, lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm trying to create a Layout for user manuals for a couple of software applications we made.

One important aspect of the layout is that it must use TrueType fonts.

In my .lyx documents, I found a "\use_non_text_fonts true" line, and I added to my layout, but it doesn't work.

Where and how I must declare this?

Comment: @Leonardo It's not clear what you are asking. What font to use seems to be a distinct issue from what the layout should be.

Comment: What you want to do is to use XeLaTeX with LyX. The following link [LyX/XeTeX](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/XeTeX) may be a bit out of date, but should get you started.

Comment: @Seamus a "layout" in LyX has nothing to do with lying out the page directly; it's (roughly) LyX's internal representation of a documentclass+engine combination.

Comment: @Seamus. I want to create something like a stylesheet for manuals, so, when I change something in it, all affected documents can be updated automatically.

Comment: @Alan, I know that, and in fact, I use XeLaTex.

Comment: @Leonardo so you want some customisation that is shared among many documents. You can do this by storing all the shared customisation in a file called `custom` or something, and then putting `\input{custom}` in each file it should apply to. Is this the sort of thing you want?

Comment: Ok.  So maybe you can clarify your question, perhaps with some sample code.  Unfortunately I don't think there are lots of LyX users here (I'm not one either).  Does making a layout = making a whole documentclass?  If that's the case, I would recommend using `memoir` as a base; (I'm assuming LyX supports memoir?) Build your layout based on the LyX memoir layout.

Comment: @Seamus. Right, I think that could help. That's something like an #include in C?.

Comment: Well, I am an experienced LyX user and willing to help. However, to me the question is unclear as well; at least I am not aware of any way to specify a particular font in a LyX layout. I would recommend to post this question to the (very helpful and responsive) [lyx-users](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc4) mailing list.